# Nested json extraction into postgres table

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, nested, bulkinsert

I have used following query to parse and store json elements into table 'pl'
'test' table is used to store raw json.

```
select     
           each_attribute ->> 'id' id,
           each_attribute ->> 'sd' sd,
           each_attribute ->> 'v' v
from       test
cross join json_array_elements(json_array) each_section
cross join json_array_elements(each_section -> 'firstt') each_attribute
```

I am able to view following json values using above query but not able to insert it into another table using json_populate_recordset.

Table definition I need to insert nested json into:
id integer, character varying(6666), character varying(99999)

Table1(for above definition) should store value for key firstt
Table2(for above definition) should store value for key secondt

Json format:

```
{
 "firstt": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sd": "test3",
      "v": "2223"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sd": "test2",
      "v": "2222"
    }],
"secondt": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sd": "test3",
      "v": "2223"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sd": "test2",
      "v": "2222"
    }]
}
```

Please assist. I have tried every possible thing from stackoverflow solutions but nothing is  given for nested array like this for insertion.

Adding code for dynamic query. It does not work. Error -'too few arguments for format'.

```
do $$
DECLARE
my record;
tb_n varchar(50);
BEGIN
FOR my IN 
  SELECT json_object_keys(json_array) as t FROM test
LOOP
tb_n := my.t;

EXECUTE format($$ WITH tbl_record_arrays as(
     SELECT
     entries.*
     FROM
       test
     JOIN LATERAL json_each(json_array) as entries(tbl_name,tbl_data_arr) ON TRUE
)
INSERT INTO %I
    SELECT
     records.*
     FROM
        tbl_record_arrays
          JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::%I,tbl_data_arr) records ON TRUE
     WHERE
      tbl_name = %I$$,tb_n);
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: `json_array_elements(json_array)` seems wrong, the `json_array` column doesn't actually contain an array - the value you've shown is an object?

Comment: "*not able to insert it into another table using json_populate_recordset.*" - please show us the query you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

To create a plpgsql function that dynamically inserts a json array for a specified key into a specified table, you can do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_json_insert(key_name text,tbl text) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
    -- the $<tag>$ syntax allows for generating a multiline string
    EXECUTE format($sql$
    INSERT INTO %1$I
        SELECT
          entries.*
        FROM test
        JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::%1$I,json_data -> $1) as entries ON TRUE;
    $sql$::text,tbl) USING dynamic_json_insert.key_name;
     END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
   VOLATILE --modifies data
   STRICT -- Returns NULL if any arguments are NULL
   SECURITY INVOKER; --Execute this function with the Role of the caller, rather than the Role that defined the function;
```

and call it like

```
SELECT dynamic_json_insert('firstt','table_1')
```

If you want to insert into multiple tables using multiple key value pairs you can make a plpgsql function that takes a `variadic` array of key,table pairs and then generate a single [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) with all of the INSERTs in a single atomic statement.

First create a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE table_key as (
    tbl_key text,
    relation regclass -- special type that refers to a Postgresql relation
);
```

Then define the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_json_insert(variadic table_keys table_key[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    DECLARE
      tbl_key_len integer = array_length(dynamic_json_insert.table_keys,1);
    BEGIN
        IF tbl_key_len > 0 THEN
        EXECUTE (
        --generates a single atomic insert CTE when there are multiple table_keys OR a single insert statement otherwise
        --the SELECT is enclosed in parenthesis because it generates a single text value which EXECUTE receives.
        SELECT
    
         --append WITH if We have more than 1 table_key (for CTE)
         CASE WHEN tbl_key_len > 1 THEN 'WITH ' ELSE '' END
         || string_agg(
          CASE
             WHEN
              --name the auxiliary statement and put it in parenthesis.
              is_aux THEN  format('%1$I as (%2$s)','ins_' || tk.tbl_key,stmt) || end_char
            ELSE stmt
          END,E'\n') || ';'
        FROM
          --unnest the table_keys argument and get its index (rn)
          unnest(dynamic_json_insert.table_keys) WITH ORDINALITY AS tk(tbl_key,relation,rn)
          -- the JOIN LATERAL here means "for each unnested table_key, generate the rows of the following subquery"
          JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT
             rn < tbl_key_len is_aux,
             --we need a comma between auxiliary statements
             CASE WHEN rn = tbl_key_len - 1 THEN '' ELSE ',' END end_char,
            --dynamically generate INSERT statement
             format($sql$
             INSERT INTO %1$I
                SELECT
                  entries.*
                FROM test
                JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::%1$I,json_data -> %2$L) as entries ON TRUE
             $sql$::text,tk.relation,tk.tbl_key) stmt
            ) stmts ON TRUE
        );
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE --modifies data
    STRICT -- Returns NULL if any arguments are NULL
    SECURITY INVOKER; --Execute this function with the Role of the caller, rather than the Role that defined the function;
```

Then call the function like:

```
SELECT dynamic_json_insert(
  ('firstt','table_1'),
  ('secondt','table_2')
);
```

Because of the use of the `variadic` keyword, you can pass in each element of the array as an individual argument and Postgres will cast to the appropriate types automatically.

The generated/executed SQL for the above function call will be:

```
WITH ins_firstt as (
             INSERT INTO table_1
                SELECT
                  entries.*
                FROM test
                JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::table_1,json_data -> 'firstt') as entries ON TRUE
             )

             INSERT INTO table_2
                SELECT
                  entries.*
                FROM test
                JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::table_2,json_data -> 'secondt') as entries ON TRUE
             ;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Very clr explanation and soln. 1doubt though, what is 'insert_tbl_1 as'? is it in continuation with 'WITH' statement(it gave error so I removed) ? Also, is there anyway to right multiple dynamic (as per key) insert statements together as the above only run one insert statement for a table at a time?

Comment: @Kush I updated my answer to add more description that hopefully will helpful. The entire block from `WITH` to the semicolon at the end is meant to run as one single query.

When you say "dynamic" do you mean like if you have keys like `firstt` , `secondt`  `thirdt` ... `<n>t` that correspond to tables `table_1` `table_2`, `table_3` ... `table_<n>`. If so you can write a plpgsql function that generates a query string that creates an auxiliary insert statement for each table and then executes it -but I'd first ask why you have so many tables with the same exact structure.

Comment: Yes,it worked now. Instead of writing multiple insert statements for each table,can I use dynamic values using format %I concept? I tried but it gives me error

Comment: @Kush ok I think I may have misunderstood what you wanted to do. I thought you were taking a json column from another table called `test`. and needing to transform and   insert values from that column into two tables. But I think what you are saying is that you have a json object in your application and you want to make a generic prepared statement to handle the insert many such objects using parameters. Is that correct?

Comment: -Yes,you are right. Ans to previous question-All tables are not of similar structures. I just gave sample here so its seems same in example json. Pls check code edit what I have been trying.

Comment: @Kush I think I see what is happening here and what you are trying to do. Can you update your question with a small example application code snippet where you are executing the SQL and passing your JSON? For example showing `cursor.execute(...)` if you are using python/psycopg2. I think that might help cut down on the confusion.

Comment: I am using postgres and trying to make procedure in which I will pass parameter as json. For above example I have stored json in test table json_array column just for testing purpose.

Comment: @Kush see my updated answer. I believe this should do what you are looking for.